# Excel: How to find all cells that contain "photographer" in a long list of links?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I find all the rows that column "A" contains the word "photographer" buried in a long URL's that are all different so that I can then extract them from the big list?

Here are some examples from the list.

http://www.borrowedandblue.com/monterey/wedding-planners-designers/astarr-events-event-floral-design

http://www.borrowedandblue.com/orange-county/wedding-photographers/andy-bang-photographers

I want to extract only the photographers from this list, not all from "orange-county"  that was just an example.

Comment: How about using the Ctrl+F to find it?

Comment: If you need an formula that does this try the Search() function?

Answer (score 2):

If you enter "photographer" in the "Find what" box, the click the "Find All" button, it will pop up a list of all entries that include the word "photographer". You can even change the "Search" drop-down to "Columns" in order to just look at a single column.
[image: Find dialog]

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I have done that, but it will only select the cells that contain photographer and I can't figure out how to select the entire row so that I could then cut and paste that into a new sheet.

Comment: @RobGoldstein You should add this requirement to your original post.

Comment: Your are right.  I have edited it.  sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your OP is still not as clear as your comment on @Joshua's answer. But if you want to be able to select all the rows which have `photographer` in column A, then I believe that filters would be the most appropriate for you.

1. Select the whole sheet and insert filters (Under 'Home', click 'Sort & Filter' > 'Filter').

   [image]
2. In column A, click on the little arrow from the filter, and use the 'Text Filters' > 'Contains...'

   [image]
3. Type 'photographer' in the first entry box and click OK.

   [image]
   [image]

Only the rows that contain `photographer` should be visible and you can select the whole sheet for copy/pasting in a new worksheet.

Comment: And if you need to get only the visible cells to somewhere else, you can use "Alt + ;" to *select only visible cells* for copy/paste

Comment: @Raystafarian I find that excel generally works well with those visible cells without taking any of those hidden cells, but of course, it's still good to take all precautions :)

Comment: Yeah, the newer versions do very well, but I wasn't sure what version this question was based on.